# Directory.GetFiles() breaks my program in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

So far I have not really programmed any apps with proper UI. To learn it, I started building a basic app that lets me open images and zap through and delete them, like the normal Windows Images app, in WPF. Realizing WPF was outdated, I wanted to move onto something more modern and I now wanted to transform my WPF app into a UWP one (I know it's getting replaced by WinUI) and I always run into the same error. Visual Studio doesn't show there is an error in the editor, but when starting the app, the apps window pops up, but Visual Studio immediately opens *App.g.i.cs* and points me to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`.

The code I present to you isn't complete, there is more where that came from, but it already stops working here, so why bother adding/showing more? The full app runs just fine in WPF without any issues.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

Now there are two things happening that I don't understand, lets start with the first one. I added comments with numbers so you can see what part of the code I am referencing.

#1:
When running the code flawlessly with WPF, I usually only had one arg in `cmdArgs`, but now there are two, which is quite confusing to me. I know that since I suspected `.GetFiles()` to receive null for some reason so I tried some stuff. Eventually I caught `cmdArgs[1]` with a breakpoint and it looked like this:

> "-ServerName:App.AppXp19csvpjy0ess769t0e3vpjdrrx8xvvk.mca"

Even if my code should dodge this bullet, because if there is an image passed to my app as an argument, the `foreach()` should set `fullArg` to be the last argument given, but I don't know why that is here. What is it and why? Is it bad, could/should I do something about it, or is it to be ignored?

#2:
Now the actual problem of the title: I set breakpoints and I get sent to *App.g.i.cs* and `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` at #2 when `Directory.GetFiles(folderPath)` should fill `tempContainer` with all present files. Now you might think "*you fool, you don't have a path the code would need to work*" but I even hardcoded a path at #3 and checked the content of `folderPath` - the program fails, even if there is a valid path to work with.

```
namespace Imager_UWP
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        // #1
        public static string[] cmdArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
   
        private string folderPath = "";
        private string fileName = "";
        private List<string> pathContainer = new List<string>();
        private int pathCounter;
        private int currentIndex = 0;
    


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            GetDirectoryPath();
            PathLoader();
        }
    
        private void GetDirectoryPath()
        {
            if (cmdArgs.Length == 1) { return; };

            string fullArg = "";
    
            foreach (string arg in cmdArgs)
            {
                fullArg = arg;
            }
            
            // #3
    
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullArg);
            folderPath = fullArg.Replace(fileName, "");
        }
    
        private void PathLoader()
        {
            if (cmdArgs.Length == 1) { return; };

            // #2: Programm shows me App.g.i.cs when running over the following line
            string[] tempContainer = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
    
            pathContainer.Clear();
    
            foreach (string path in tempContainer)
            {
                if (path.Contains(".jpg") || path.Contains(".jpeg") || path.Contains(".png"))
                {
                    pathContainer.Add(path);
                }
            }
    
            pathCounter = pathContainer.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to find the source of my problem on the internet, but I wasn't successful with my search. So I hope any of you guys can point me to my problem/mistake and tell me how to fix it. I don't believe `Directory.GetFiles()` is inherently a bad way to get all files in a directory right?

Comment: When it breaks at `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`, you can see the exception message and stack trace in the `e` variable. Could you update your question with the content of `e.ToString()`?

Comment: e.Message:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is empty.
Parameter name: path
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.

harcoding folderPath looks like: C:\\Users\\wolf-\\Desktop\\myImages\\

Comment: to get a folder from a file use Path.GetDirectoryName

Comment: Path.GetDirectoryName is probably better, I wasnt aware of that. But that doesnt change the string thats getting fed into GetFiles. Its still C:\\Users\\wolf-\\Desktop\\myImages\\.

Comment: looks like you are passing an empty path somewhere

Comment: When I researched the problem, I saw that similar issues were due to that, passing an emtpy path, I mean. But thats exactly why I did check wether folderPath was null or a valid path. I dont really understand how this is popping up when the string entering GetFiles is empty/invalid.

Comment: @Nico1395 use `Path` as suggested by others and avoid sending in an empty string. You'll want a valid path. You can check it with `Directory.Exists()`. Path does not care if it is a real location - it builds valid paths, it doesn't ensure that they exist.

Comment: @VicF Ah! That worked, I should have thought of that! Thanks a lot guys. Is there a way to mark your comment as an answer? I have never asked a question here myself, not sure what I can and cannot do.

Comment: You might think about wrapping that call to `Directory.GetFiles(folderPath)` in a `try`/`catch` block so you can handle the exception yourself and report it to the user. If you haven't done that before, see here: [Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/exception-handling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing we need to know is that UWP apps are running in the sandbox and UWP apps are isolated from the system. If you want to get files in UWP apps, you need to use Windows Runtime API like [Windows.Storage Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage?view=winrt-22621). The behavior you've got is because you are using some .net API to get files via Path, it works in WPF apps, but it is not allowed in UWP apps.

The second thing is that UWP apps have some limitations when accessing system resource like files. UWP apps could access some places by default like the application data locations. If you want to access other places like picture library, you will need to declare a capability in the mainfest file of the UWP app. More information here:[File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

If you really need to access a file in a place where UWP apps can't access or you want to get the file via path, you will need to use a restricted capability- `broadFileSystemAccess`. Add this capability in the manifest file of your app and enable this in **Settings > Privacy > File system** after deployed your app. Then you could call API from **Windows.Storage Namespace** to get file by path.

Comment: So in other words loading paths as a string with Directory or Path methods cant be done, instead I should use Classes like for example [StorageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder?view=winrt-22621) or for example? Alright thanks for the info, ill play around with it!

Comment: @Nico1395 Yes, if you want to load file by path, you will need to add `broadFileSystemAccess` capability and use `StorageFolder` and `StorageFile`.

Comment: @Nico1395 Does it work for you to get files using `StorageFolder` API via **broadFileSystemAccess**?

Comment: Hey! Yes it did work quite well. But I ran into other issues too and I figured I should probably start off learning UI with something a little more easy. WPF is older but I feel like its a little easier and the App that I started programming works pretty well and I am learning a lot. But I will start trying out UWP later when my current project is "finished" and I hopefully write better code. Currently using Streams works very well for me, but later I am certain Windows.Storage will be of much Help, thank you!